# Permanently delete/remove blog-articles perhaps automatically with rule?

Tags: .htaccess, modx, modx-evolution

I have an articles-blog and my articles may have a shelf-life of perhaps 1-2 weeks max. In my .htaccess I already have ExpiresByType rules (but the clutter in my MODx backend is still there and I do not understand the impact of these rules - code is below). I also have put my articles standard as indexable by the search engines.

When the shelf-life expires, I would like to permanently delete my articles. Now I do this manually and I have a whole lot of "red-crossed-out" articles titles in my back-end which makes me completely loose the overview.

My question is: What is MODx EVO best practise for my situation and is there an "automatic" way to permanently and completely (so no more red-crossed-out resource titles) remove expired articles from my MODx backend with pre-defined rules (for example, "if published time-period on the internet is 20 days then delete/remove article from MODx backend/database)"?

```html
## Leverage Browser Caching ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## Leverage Browser Caching ##
```

Comment: The content of the `.htaccess` file is just for the cache in the browser, which means that anyone that visits your page will cache (download) all your jpg for 1 year by default if the checksum is the same. This does obviously not work for content within MODX, as cache is not the same as a resource. You could automate/move/unpublish/thrash resources after they have been posted with a plugin or something. It's been a while since I did Evo previously, so I am afraid I can not produce any code for you.

Comment: @OptimusCrime - Thank you for replying. I am researching the options here and a plugin would be great. Would you know of any such plugin in REVO? That could help me find something useful. Regarding custom code for delete/trash/unpublish resources, you mean a PHP snippet? There must be something because I guess its quite a "common" "problem" with article blog sites...